# How to add symbol in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add \ in a string but not working.

```
var jhon="michel";
var test=jhon +"\"+ "robert";

alert(test)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: ....double it: \\

Comment: Can you edit it?

Comment: Thanks..Working good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way

```js
var jhon= "michel";
var test= `${jhon}\\robert`;

//for old browsers

var test2 =jhon +"\\"+ "robert"; 

console.log(test)
console.log(test2)
```

Comment: For latest browser versions, yes. And unless you're using IE. :-/

Answer (score 2):

`\` is reserved as an `escape` character -- You you have to, in essence, escape the escape character. IE

```
var test=jhon +"\\"+ "robert";
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `test=jhon +"\"+ "robert"` you're just escaping the `"` character (which generates an error in that case). Instead, you should write the `\` two times.

```js
var jhon = "michel",
  test = jhon + "\\" + "robert";

console.log(test); /** output: michel\robert **/
```